# Using angular-directives within JSF

Tags: angularjs, jsf

I am trying to use angular together with an JSF backend.

I have the problem that custom directives are not processed within JSF when set as attributes for example:

```
<div my-directive .... > ...(some code)... </div>
```

JSF or XHTML sais that is not allowed to use attributes withtout being assigned (with an =).
To workaround, I used

```
<div my-directive ="" ...> ...(some code)... </div>
```

That would be fine with angularFS  but when using the attribute 
"my-directive" it will be removed after JSF rendering completely. The problem is my html relies on JSF ajax calls to a DB that I need as the backend relies on JSF 2.2/JSP.

The only thing I can bring it to work is using a tag/an element like
`<my-directive> ... </my-directive>`

Doing so is somewhat undesireable as I would like to use an attribute.

I learnt that JSF can be tricky if used with angularFS.
Did someone have this issue before?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: You're going to have to provide a little more information for anyone to be able to help you. What do you mean "ignored", are there any errors in the console, how is your application set up, are you seeing this in all browsers?

Comment: Why did you down vote my question? 

When I write a angular directive and I try to use my newly created directed as attribute, JSF igonores it.
That means it got deleted in the DOM altough I have set it like this:

<div my-directive=""...>

Comment: I found a solution by my own:

If using custom directives with angular on JSF (here: 2.2), it has to be done with elements (not attributes) like so:

<my-directive> ...code... </my-directive>

After I changed it, my custom directive was applied correctly by angular.

It would be nice removing your down vote, you could up vote it instead!

Comment: It was not me who downvoted, as I generally like to comment and try to help instead when something is wrong. You provided way too little information for anyone to be able to give you an answer (which is why it was put on hold by the way). It is highly unlikely that your problem had anything to do with JSF.

Comment: No it is not. JSF has its own way interpreting attributes. For example it is not possible to use my-directive without assigning any value to this attribute. Outside of JSF the same code worked (for to say HTML5 and not XHTML/JSF). So to be more precise, XHTML and its stricter way of interpreting the DOM is the cause.

Can you agree?

Comment: In that case you're right about JSF. That you're using attributes and that it works outside of JSF is information that could have been included in the original question by the way. Keep in mind when using elements that IE8 is not a big fan of custom tags, so if you need to support it include something like      <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <script>
        document.createElement('my-directive');
      </script>
    <![endif]--> before the directive is used.

Comment: As I posted the question I did not try to let it work outside of JSF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, JSF2.2 does what you need. It allows either to go with pure Html5 and bind with JSF or go with JSF and use p:passthrough.

@see a few links below
[Link 1](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/TagDecorator.html), [Link 2](http://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/08/08/jsf22-html5/), [Link 3](http://en.kodcu.com/2013/08/jsf-2-2-html-5-support/)

Comment: That looks good - and will be a good option after I am able to switch to JSF2.2 (still I am obliged to use 2.1).
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The links you provided are really helpful.